# DB2 - Error "The "WITH ISOLATION USE AND KEEP" clause is not allowed"

Tags: db2

We are using DB2(v 9.7, Unix platform). I have a stored procedure having following SQL statements in it.

```
declare SOME_DATE             DATE;
declare SOME_INT             Integer;
…
set SOME_DATE = ( Select SOME_COLUMN from SOME_TABLE WHERE ID= IN_PARAM_ID);
set SOME_INT = ( Some query that accesses federated table using nick name);
```

I wanted to add WITH UR to first SELECT statement which fetches SOME_DATE.

When I do that, proc fails to compile with following error.

> SQL0109N The "WITH ISOLATION USE AND KEEP" clause is not allowed.
>   SQLSTATE=42601 (42601,-109)

If i stop accessing federated table, proc compiles fine.
How is adding With UR to first SELECT query related to accessing nick named/federated table in 2nd select ?

Comment: Question is incomplete, unless you give details of the target of the nickname (i.e. which data source type, and which options are used for the nickname/server/data-source ). Some data-sources don't support that syntax, and there are other documented restrictions.

Comment: @mao why do details of nick names matter ? I am not using WiTH UR in query that accesses nick name. I am using it in query which fetches SOME_DATE and only accesses local tables.

Comment: Because details matter. Things are rarely what they appear. Details let others try to recreate the symptom. If you provide a *minimal complete example* to show the symptom, then you might find the cause, but others can attempt to recreate, find workarounds, find root cause etc.

Answer (score 0):

There must be "WITH UR" in query some where.Please remove it and run the query.